# How to find $y''(x)$ if $y(x)=\ln(\sec x+\tan x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I have a function:
$y = \ln(\sec(x) + \tan(x))$

I have found the first derivative:
$\left(\sec \left(x\right)\tan \left(x\right)+\sec ^2\left(x\right)\right)\dfrac{1}{\sec \left(x\right)+\tan \left(x\right)}$

How do I go about finding the $y''$ given the function $y = \ln(\sec(x) + \tan(x))$?

Answer (score 4):

By factoring out $\sec(x),$ that derivative reduces to
$$y'(x)=\sec(x),$$
so 
$$y''(x)=\sec(x)\tan(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should simplify:

$$y'=\sec(x)\frac{\sec(x)+\tan(x)}{\sec(x)+\tan(x)}=\sec(x)=\frac1{\cos(x)}$$

This is then in the form of something you'd want to tackle with chain rule, where the outer function is $f(x)=1/x$ and the inner function is $g(x)=\cos(x)$, both of which have derivatives you know.

Thus, to find higher (more than the second derivative because this answer is overkill), you'll want to apply [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula), which says:

$$y^{(n+1)}={d^n \over dx^n} f(g(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(g(x))\cdot B_{n,k}\left(g'(x),g''(x),g'''(x),\dots,g^{(n-k+1)}(x)\right)$$

$$\small=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^kk!}{\cos^{k+1}(x)}\cdot B_{n,k}\left(-\sin(x),-\cos(x),\sin(x),\dots,(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k+2}2\right\rfloor}\begin{cases}\cos(x)&n-k+1\equiv0\pmod2\\\sin(x)&n-k\equiv1\pmod2\end{cases}\right)$$

where $B_{n,k}$ are the [Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomial).